# iOS 13.x Safari Dark Mode <optgroup> not visible and cannot style them for a web-app

Tags: css, ios13, optgroup, ios-darkmode

I have a web-app that has a dark background as per client colors.  The problem I am having is that when the device is in Dark Mode, the `<optgroup>` for iOS Safari displays the text from the label in `<optgroup label='---Cars----'></optgroup>` in black...hence making it invisible/undetectable from the background.  I have tried using the following to change the color but it is ignored....emulators and/or Developer Mode on PC/Mac display properly but is doesn't on a real device.

```
 @media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
    optgroup {
        color:grey;
    }
 }
 @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
    optgroup {
       color:white;
    }
 }
```

If Apple has locked down styling in mobile Safari for `<select>` and `<optgroup>` tags on iOS devices is this a miss that the browser leaves the tag in black while on black background?

I have also tried adding a `class` to the `<optgroup>` and that doesn't work either....

Any insights to changing the color of the text in an `<optgroup>` would be greatly appreciated!